# Why I'm getting two lines in one when I have an specific size

Tags: c

I have a file with 3 lines like this:

```
 1234567890 
 abcdefghij 
 ABCDEFGHIJ
```

And I want to reverse the lines and send it to the same file like this:

```
 ABCDEFGHIJ
 abcdefghij 
 1234567890
```

But i'm getting a blank line and the last two lines in the same line:

[image]

This is my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
        char filename[512];
        memset(filename, 0, 512);

        puts("Input file name:");
        scanf("%s", filename);

        FILE * file = fopen(filename, "rb");
        if (file == NULL){
                printf("Cannot open file %s \n", filename);
                exit(0);
        }
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        long size = ftell(file);
        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);
        char * buffer = (char *)malloc(size);
        fread(buffer, 1, size, file);
        fclose(file);

        char *token;
        token = strtok(filename, ".");
        strcat(token, ".txt.OUT");

        file = fopen(filename, "wb");
        for (long i = size; i > 0; i--)
        {
                long j = 0;
                while (buffer[i - j] != '\n' && i - j > 0)
                        j++;
                fwrite(&buffer[i - j], 1, j, file);
                i -= j;
        }
        fclose(file);
        free(buffer);

        return 0;
}
```

Update: 
When I write in the file if I do `fwrite(&buffer[i - (j-2)], 1, j, file);` I get the three lines correctly but without both A and without the numbers 12

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208299/discussion-on-question-by-lluis-why-im-getting-two-lines-in-one-when-i-have-an).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    #include<stdio.h>
void main() {
    FILE *fi=fopen("input.txt","r");
    if(fi==NULL) {
        printf("File does not exist...");
        exit(0);
    }
    static char ch[255][255];
    for(int i=0;1;i++) {
        fscanf(fi,"%s",ch[i]);
        if(getc(fi)==EOF) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fi);
    FILE *fo=fopen("output.txt","w");
    for(int i=254;i>=0;i--) {
        if(ch[i][0]!='\0') {
            fputs(ch[i],fo);
            fputs("\n",fo);
        }
    }
    fclose(fo);
    printf("Done...");
}
```

Comment: This works but I have 2 files, one with 4 lines (one blank line) and one without a blank line, only 3 lines and both return the same number of lines and should not, anyway, you can explain why in the first loop you put 1 and what do you do in the second loop? Thanks

Comment: How can anyone know the number of lines in the input file so , In first loop i put 1 on conditional place thus the loop execute infinite times , when the file pointer reach at EOF(end of file) it breaks the first loop . And in second loop it retrieve string from 'ch' array from it's last index to 0th index to perform the desired task , and it prints only only the not null string . Thank you

Comment: Understanded now, in case I want to print the blank line too, what I need to do? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The program having read the `size` bytes of a file into `buffer`, this is the bit responsible for (incorrectly) writing the output:

> ```
>         for (long i = size; i > 0; i--)
>         {
>                 long j = 0;
>                 while (buffer[i - j] != '\n' && i - j > 0)
>                         j++;
>                 fwrite(&buffer[i - j], 1, j, file);
>                 i -= j;
>         }
> ```

Note first that as was expressed in comments, that code overruns the end of `buffer`.  It having been allocated as length `size`, `buffer`'s valid indices are from 0 to `size - 1`, inclusive, yet you attempt to access `buffer[size]` when `i == size` and `j == 0`.  Do fix that.

Second, it's pretty easy to see why you get an initial blank line.  On the first pass through the outer loop, you scan backwards until you find a `j` such that `buffer[i-j] == '\n'`.  You then write a segment of the buffer *starting at that position*, so the first character written is a newline.  You probably want instead to output the data starting after the newline.

Continuing from there, the rest becomes clear.  On the second pass, you do the same thing, so again the first character written is a newline.  That is the newline that appears at the end of "ABCDEFGHIJ".  On the third pass, however, you reach the beginning of the buffer without encountering another newline.  You correctly avoid overrunning the beginning of the buffer, but this time, the first character written is not a newline, because there isn't one at the beginning of the buffer.

Your best bet for proper line splitting is to avoid copying newlines from the buffer altogether.  Copy only the data between the newlines, and add your own newlines manually where they are needed.

Comment: Okey thanks, but how I copy the data between the lines? I tried before with some function but didn't work

Comment: @Lluis, it's just a question of choosing the correct starting position and number of bytes for each write.  Your program already has pretty much everything needed.  It just needs to be tweaked a bit.  When you've found a newline, start one byte later and write one byte fewer (but then add a newline after).  When you reach the beginning of the buffer without finding a newline, do what you're already doing.

Comment: I still can't solve it, I just don't know how to implement it, I'm pretty new to c

Comment: Well, @Lluis, I'm afraid I can't see how to offer better advice without rewriting your code for you, which I am determined not to do.  We are open to providing homework help, but generally we try to avoid outright doing people's homework for them.  Among other things, it defeats the purpose of the exercise.